# Rails 4 - change pluralize rules

Tags: ruby-on-rails, i18n-gem

How can we change the pluralize rules for translations in Rails 4? I tried to modify the initialisers/inflections.rb as follows:

```
ActiveSupport::Inflector.inflections(:fr) do |inflect|
   inflect.irregular 'Niveau', 'Niveaux'
end

ActiveSupport::Inflector.inflections(:fr) do |inflect|
  inflect.acronym 'RESTful'
end
```

and pass the translation in the page like that:

```
= link_to t('links.back_to', model: Level.model_name.human.pluralize), levels_path
```

but it is still translated by applying the default patterns. Any idea on how to fix that ? Thank you

Comment: Did you restart the server after making the change?

Comment: Did you tried `'Niveau'.pluralize(:fr)` in the rails console?

Comment: Sure, I restarted the server after the changes. When trying in console: [1] pry(main)> Level.model_name.human.pluralize
=> "Niveaus"
[2] pry(main)> Level.model_name.human.pluralize(:fr)
=> "Niveaux". So passing the locale everywhere in the views is a little bit DRYless :) Any other solution ?